# Remove mulitipul H1 Tags from Homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, home

I was checking for H1 tags on my home page and found that i have 3.
1 is from the logo which i believe is acceptable for Seo. 
There are two others, one is the category-title and i dont know where the 3rd comes from. 
Firstly how can i change the homepage category title Tag H1 to something else, or better still what should it be. (without changing other page category titles)
Seconedly where does the other H1 tag come from? and how can i remove it or change it.
Hope somebody can advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The H1 tags will likely be in either the CMS (a page, or static block, for example) or in `.phtml` templates. Since the store in question is running a custom theme, it is hard to tell from an outside perspective without access to the source code or admin panel.

That being said, I suspect that the H1 in the header banner with the contents: "Timports Ltd", is likely in a static block, or perhaps a page. If that is the case, you can fix that by finding the block or page that contains that text and changing it to a different heading tag.

The third H1 on the page that has the contents of "Kiln Dried Firewood" is probably being output from the CMS, but in a little different way. It looks like a category title that is being display through a widget or something similar. If that is the case, you may need to adjust the template that is rendering that block on the main page.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you can find them in static blocks.

A lot of times a good strategy is to just search the contents of your website via Linux command.

```
grep -r "Stuff you are looking for"
```

You can search for things like html ids, they are most of times unique. Even if they are not, you should not get too many results. Make sure to give grep some time to finish, it can take about a minute or two depending on your server speed.

As was mentioned here, it is hard to tell just from the website where the location your tags are. You can also try switching on the template hints from the admin panel. It will show you exactly which phtml files are rendered during you page load, and which content they are loading.